# There is an error in my code, '1- dimensional array of double cannot be converted too boolean'

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bubble-sort

Sorry i'm new to all this, i don't know how to fix my bubble sort , i have an array but i have 2 errors in my code, so i don't even know if it works or how to fix it help would be very much appreciated. 
    My first error said '1- dimensional array of double cannot be converted too boolean' and second error said 'identifier expected' Both errors occur on line 23

'Declares the name of the sorted Array
    Dim SortedArray(49) As Integer
    'Declares the name for the Unsorted Array
    Dim UnSortedArray(49) As Double

```
Private Sub BtnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStart.Click

    'Declare Random Numbers, NumberRange and the Name of the array
    Dim RandomNumber As New Random
    Dim NumberRange As Integer
    Dim swap As Boolean

    'Declares the Values of the numbers only be between 0 and 100
    Randomize(NumberRange)
    For NumberRange = 0 To 49
    Next
    'Creates and Array with 100 RandomNumbers with values inbetween 0 and 100
    SortedArray(NumberRange) = RandomNumber.Next(0, 100)
    UnSortedArray(NumberRange) = UnSortedArray(NumberRange)

    'Adds the items onto the ListBox
    LstUnSorted.Items.Add(UnSortedArray(NumberRange).ToString)

    swap = False

    For i = 1 To UnSortedArray(49) - 1

        If UnSortedArray ([i]-1) > UnSortedArray[i] Then
            UnSortedArray(i - 1) = UnSortedArray([i])

            swap = True

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You seem to be using VB.net but your question is tagged with VBA

Comment: You're mixing [] with (), you're swap algorithm doesn't swap it only copied and you need two for loop for a bubble sort.

Comment: Oh thank you, i switched the [] with (). where would i put the for loop? , sorry, i'm new to this.